# Need help in setting up UI based testing for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, selenium, integration

I am leading a team which develops application based on Ruby on Rails. Since the application was small, automated testing was not given much importance. But lately it has started growing in size. I am seriously thinking of enforcing the testing discipline in the team.

For all the new code that is being committed, I want my developers to do a 100% code coverage. But the problem is that they are resistant to write tests for UI related changes. I read online that Selenium is one of the solutions for UI testing.

Can anyone share me a link to blog or tutorial which teaches me how to set up Selenium or some other automated UI testing for Rails. The version I use is 2.3.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the two mainstream Acceptance testing frameworks:

- [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/)
- [Steak](https://github.com/cavalle/steak) (minimalist approach)

Best place to start (in my opinion): Railscasts. Try the [beginning with cucumber](http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber) railscast.

Your "code" will end up looking like

```
Feature: pay bill on-line
  In order to reduce the time I spend paying bills
  As a bank customer with a checking account
  I want to pay my bills on-line

  Scenario: pay a bill
    Given checking account with $50
    And a payee named Acme
    And an Acme bill for $37
    When I pay the Acme bill
    Then I should have $13 remaining in my checking account
    And the payment of $37 to Acme should be listed in Recent Payments
```

Code found on http://iain.nl/2011/01/cucumber-vs-steak/

Comment: Following up on Jesse's answer, we user Cucumber with selenium and are pretty happy with it.